# Need script to delete the old backup file from storage blob , the script need to run from managed instance

Tags: azure-sql-database

Can anyone help me to get the script to remove the backup file older than 45 days from storage Blob container.
Actually i want to run the script in Managed instance ( PAAS) through SQL server agent job.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

According this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df73b5a3-d27b-45ee-b440-c1bed99f9b4e/how-to-automate-bak-delete-from-azure-blob).
I think you can modifier the PS script. Change `$FromDate = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-6)).Date`  to `$FromDate = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-45)).Date` . The script is as follows:

```
#PowerShell Script to delete System Databases .bak files from Azure Block Blob

#-eq = equals

#-ne = not equals

#-lt = less than

#-gt = greater than

#-le = less than or equals

#-ge = greater than or equals

#Set All Variables

$YesterdayDate = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date   #Get Yesterday date

$FromDate = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-45)).Date        #Get 6 Days back date from Today

$BlobType = "Pageblob"

$bacs = Get-ChildItem $location -Filter *.bak

$container="dwhdatabasesbackup"

$StorageAccountName="analytics"

$StorageAccountKey="xxxxxx"
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$filelist = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $context

#Foreach Loop With a Condition $_.LastModified.Date -eq $YesterdayDate to make Sure there was a File Uploaded Yesterday 

  
foreach ($filein$filelist | Where-Object {$_.LastModified.Date -eq $YesterdayDate -and $_.BlobType -eq $BlobType -and ($_.Name -like "*.bak")})

{

    
$Yesterdayfile = $file.Name

    
if ($Yesterdayfile -ne $null)

    {

        
$FileFullLength = $Yesterdayfile.Length

        
$FileNameWithoutDatePart = $Yesterdayfile.SubString(0, $FileFullLength-30)

        Write-Output ("File Name Without Date Part: " +$FileNameWithoutDatePart)

        
#Foreach Loop With a Condition $_.LastModified.Date -lt $FromDate to Remove Files those are 5 Days Old 

          
foreach ($filein$filelist | Where-Object {$_.LastModified.Date -lt $FromDate -and $_.BlobType -eq $BlobType -and ($_.Name -like "$FileNameWithoutDatePart*.bak")})

        {


        $removefile = $file.Name

        $RemoveFileFullLength = $removefile.Length     


       
$ModifiedDate = $file.LastModified.Date


        if (($removefile -ne $null) -and ($RemoveFileFullLength -eq $FileFullLength))

            {

                Write-Output ("Remove File Name: ("+$removefile +") as Modified Date: ("+ $ModifiedDate +") of File is Older Than Date: ("+ $FromDate + ")")

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: managed instance is server less solution so from where we will execute this powershell command  , can you please help

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with managed instance serverless solution.  Is this documnetation [Use Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/powershell-script-content-guide?tabs=single-database)  helpful for you? Or this [one](https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/change-size-of-azure-sql-managed-instance-using-powershell/)?

Comment: Hi@sandip kumar, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.